# Magento 2.3.1 Override vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/js/theme.js

Tags: magento2.3, requirejs-config.js

I need to override `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/js/theme.js` to my custom theme in `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/`

I found that I need to do it through requirejs-config.js with map but I didn't find the way to do it.

Where should I create the requirejs-config.js and what I have to write in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the theme.js file to the below path

`app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/web/js/`

Run `bin/magento s:s:d`

It'll work for you.

Comment: It works thank you very much

Comment: Cheers!!! Have a great day!